# Elasticsearch sort parent by inner hits doc count

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I am indexing into Elasticsearch a bunch of `Product`s and `Store`s in which the product is available. For example, a document looks something like:

```
{
  name: "iPhone 6s",
  price: 600.0,
  stores: [
    {
      name: "Apple Store Union Square",
      location: "San Francisco, CA"
    },
    {
      name: "Target Cupertino",
      location: "Cupertino, CA"
    },
    {
      name: "Apple Store 5th Avenue",
      location: "New York, NY"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

and using the `nested` type, the mappings will be:

```
"mappings" : {
  "product" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "price" : {
        "type" : "float"
      },
      "stores" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "location" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a query to find all the products that are available in certain location, say "CA", and then sort by the number of stores matched. I know Elasticsearch has a [inner hit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-inner-hits.html) feature which allows me to find hits in the nested `Store` documents, but is sorting `Product` based on the `doc_count` of the inner hit possible? And to extend the question further, is sorting the parent documents based on some inner aggregation possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is possible. Currently you are not getting expected results because by default `score_mode` parameter is `avg` in [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html), so if 5 stores match the given product they might be scored lower than say one which matches 2 stores only because the `_score` is calculated by taking average.

This problem can be solved by `summing` all the `inner hits` by specifying `score_mode` as `sum`. One minor problem could be [field length norm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#field-norm) i.e **match in shorter field gets higher score** than bigger field. so in your example *Cupertino, CA* will get bit higher `score` than *San Francisco, CA*. You can check this behavior with `inner hits`. To solve this you need to disable the `field norms`. Change `location mapping` to

```
"location": {
    "type": "string",
    "norms": {
        "enabled": false
    }
}
```

After that this query will give you desired results. I included `inner hits` to demonstrate `equal score` for every matched nested doc.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "stores",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "stores.location": "CA"
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

This will `sort` the products based on the number of stored matched.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that by manipulating the score I can solve this particular problem in the way that you suggested. But if I extend the problem a little bit by saying that `price` is now a property of `Store` instead of `Product`, and that I have a `nested_min_aggregation` to find me the minimum price available for a particular product. I want to show all the products sorted by their respective min price, is that possible?

Comment: I cant say for 100%, it is possible as I did not understand everything, but if you could ask another question with your current query and more details, me or somebody else will have a look at it and you will get a response.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You just saved my day!! I was having hard time to boost according to inner hits count and score_mode definitely did the job